# How To See The Dimension Of A Still Image in Adobe Premier

Tags: premiere, cs5

I added an Image to a video layer, by default premier scaled it up 323x its original size. I want to be able to see the resulting dimension in pixels. Is there a way to see dimensions of an element in a scene. Same question applies to titles. If i add a title to a video layer, and i scale it, is there a way to see what the resulting pixel dimension is.